# Best way to access computer CMD from android

Tags: android, windows, client

I'd like to create and Android app which allows me to control some aspects of my computer (volume, open pre-defined URL's..etc).

Would it be feasible to create a Windows client from an Android device? I'd like to access my PC's terminal in order to execute some commands.

If so..could you please point me out the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you should create a server app that must be installed in the client computer, the connection could be by sockets or http/rest so the android app could connect easily

Answer (score 1):

One possibitly (maybe not the best one) would be to host a apache webserver with access to the cmd by executing it with PHP. You could predefine commands which you call from specific URL paths like `http://192.168.1.1/myHomeControl/muteSpeakers/` for muting the speakers.

You can execute cmd commands in PHP with

```
exec('ping');
```

or

```
system('ping');
```

Then you just need to call the URL from your android Device and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this software -- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh

Install the ssh on your machine:

1. For Mac:
   http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_enable_ssh_your_mac
2. For
   Linux:
   http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-installing-and-using-ssh-client-server-in-linux/
3. For Windows:
   http://comptb.cects.com/install-configure-ssh-on-windows/

Connect to it and do whatever you want to do. Have Fun!

---

If you want to create an application, than there is two options again: either you create a SSH tunel to the pc and you kinda let the user configure their SSH or create an External APP such the PHP , or VB.net that kinda detects by protocols and different ports the access to the machine.

I use this software to control volume and stuff : http://www.unifiedremote.com/ it is pretty good when it comes to control the laptop and and certain types even using the mobile as a mousepad -- To do this they created a software that needs to be installed on the machine to control doing so lets call this software the CONVERTER / RECEPTOR that converts all request that i do from mobile to the pc. Seems simple but not rlly :)

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for that amazing answer. Mi idea is to create an app in order to have all commands behind the user eyes. I mean, the user press the volume up button and volume increases.. That's my idea. I just want to get some knowledge in this field.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to control Windows machine from another device. Every type of connection depends on particular type of protocol. And as result each protocol has its own rules, pros and cons and restrictions.

You can connect to the machine by [SSH using JSCH](http://eridem.net/android-tip-021-ssh-execute-remote-commands-with-android/). But you also need to install SSH server on your machine.

Or you can develop your own protocol using TCP/UDP as transport.